# counting country id's of the region they are associated with

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I am currently trying to combine the list of countries id's to their region so when routed to the browser it shows up at "the region", #number of countries in that region.  For example, I am currently getting western europe listed 9 times, instead of once with the number 9 next to it.  How do I combine the two using django and sqlite3.  below is an example of my code.

```
countries = Countries.objects.values('region', 'id').order_by('-region')
total_countries = Countries.objects.count()
print(total_countries)
print(countries.query)
return render(req, 'worldApp/index.html', context={'countries':countries})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
Countries.objects.values('region').annotate(Count('id')).order_by('-region')
```

[See docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/aggregation/#values)